# Unreliable randomizing or loading of images

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, shuffle

I want to randomly display some images stored as attributes on an entity "Disc" in Core Data. I've been using the Swift `Array.shuffled()` function performed on the `fetchedObjects` of my `NSFetchedResultsController` "`thisFRC.`"

First problem was that the desired images often did not appear when they should. Here's code that produced this problem. It's part of a function `loadImages`, which is called from `viewWillAppear`:

```
try thisFRC.performFetch()

                fetchedData = thisFRC.fetchedObjects as! [Disc]
                shuffledDiscs = fetchedData.shuffled()

                thisDisc = shuffledDiscs [0]
```

Second problem was that when they did appear, I would very often see the same image repeated several (or many) times. I thought maybe the images were persisting for some unknown reason, so I did:

```
frontImageView.image = nil
rearImageView.image = nil
```

in `prepareForSegue`. Same problem upon returning to the original View Controller.

Third problem arose when I tried to fix the second problem by further randomizing the order of the images with the code below. It crashes at the commented line with this error: “Index out of range”.

```
 try thisFRC.performFetch()

            fetchedData = thisFRC.fetchedObjects as! [Disc]
            shuffledIndices = fetchedData.indices.shuffled()
            index = shuffledIndices [0]  // Crashes here with “Index out of range”
            shuffledDiscs = fetchedData.shuffled()

            thisDisc = shuffledDiscs [index]
```

**My questions:**

1) Why doesn't the `shuffled()` function do a better job of randomizing? To be fair, I tried this code in a separate test app, and it seemed to work fine. If I can clear this up, I can dispense with my workaround.

2) I don't understand how the index could be out of range in `index = shuffledIndices [0]`

**Note:**

The images I'm using are quite large -- on the order of 2400 x 2400 -- being squeezed into a 160 x 160 image view, so the early anomalies could possibly be caused by scaling.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

TIA

**Resolved!**

With insight from @Adis, and a thousand `print()` lines, I discovered the problem:

There was a function extraneously inserting a new Disc entity into my context every time I segued to one of the two connected View Controllers. This accounted for the "ghost" items that were showing up with no `UIImage` attributes, creating blank ImageViews. Once I deleted these anomalies, and killed the function that created them, everything works fine. I was also able to just use the `shuffled()` function without the extra flourish I had put on it.

All is well, and thanks to all who took the time to look!

Comment: For whatever reason, it looks that at the point you're shuffling, you have an empty array of images, which only populates at some later point of time, which explains both - fetching by index in an empty array crashes, and the images not being shuffled, since shuffling is done before the actual images are fetched.

Comment: @Adis-- Many thanks for your insight! Please see edit above...